# Android Picasso lazy load

Tags: android, loading, lazy-evaluation, picasso

I am using Picasso library in my android project. I have a ListView in my main activity. All row items are filled with data from XML which is parsed using SAXParser. I have created custom list adapter which handels list items. How can I achieve some kind of lazy loading of images with Picasso. Here is my code (of custom adapter):

```
public class PicassoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public PicassoAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
    {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
         return data.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.pid); // title
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.slika1);//  slika

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        Log.i("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&",data.get(0).get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE));

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_TITLE));
        Picasso.with(vi.getContext()).load(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL)).into(image);  
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by lazy load?  The getView() method will only be called when the view is about to come on screen.  Picasso will then fetch and load the image into the ImageView.  This already is lazy loading.

Comment: I am more-less android rookie. Images in listview item's are loading so slowly.I have to wait aprox 30 sec. till one image is loaded.

Comment: 30 seconds could be a slow download, a huge bitmap or a combination. I recommend you check the images you download and use `fit()` or `resize()`.

Answer (score 0):

For `ListView` its require placeholder

```
Picasso.with(vi.getContext())
    .load(song.get(MainActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL))
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(image);
```